# im making a script python that runs another script but it just keep running onl the first one the second one never

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''imports'''
import os
import sys
'''flags'''
i = input('flags for secretflavour?')
'''where to'''
w =bool(input())


if {w == 1}:
    while True:
            os.system(f"./secretflavour.py {i}")
            exit()
    while False:
            os.system(f"./chopchop.sh {i}")
            exit()
```

Comment: i know but i cant

Comment: im lazy a little bit

Comment: but thats what i did

Comment: then i got little bit lazy and asked my self

Comment: and you have to be nice to new contributor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement always evaluates to true (it evaluates either to `{true}` or `{false}`, which are both truthy, being sets of 1+ element).

You're looking for

```
if w == 1:
```

Beyond that, the code doesn't make much sense anyway... perchance you're looking for

```
if w:
   os.system(f"./secretflavour.py {i}")
else:
   os.system(f"./chopchop.sh {i}")
```